# PHP não consegue puxar dados do banco, usando Bootstrap

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, twitter-bootstrap, formulário

Tenho um formulário em PHP onde apresenta os dados do usuário logado. Segue código:

```
Precisa de troco?<br>
<input name="troco" type="text" id="troco" value=" Nenhum" size="60"><br><br>

Nome:<br>
<input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" size="60" value="<? echo $nome ?>"><br><br>

Endereço:<br>
<input id="endereco" name="endereco" type="text" size="60" value="<? echo $endereco ?>"><br><br>

CEP:<br>
<input id="cep" name="cep" type="text" size="60" value="<? echo $cep ?>"><br><br>

Bairro:<br>
<input id="bairro" name="bairro" type="text" size="60" value="<? echo $bairro ?>"><br><br>

Telefone(s):<br>
<input id="telefone" name="telefone" type="text" size="60" value="<? echo $telefone ?>"><br><br>

Email:<br>
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" size="60" value="<? echo $email ?>"><br><br>
```

Depois que coloquei o Bootstrap para deia-lo responsivo, ele parou de retornar os dados, apresenta agora sempre o valor 1 nos campos. Já fiz o teste, tirando, mudando a div que faz a responsividade:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> </div>
```

Quando tiro ela, o formulário funciona, apresentando os dados corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

primeiramente você deve melhorar as aberturas das tags php, o correto é:

```
<?php echo $bairro; ?>
```

o bootstrap não tem o "poder" de estragar nada no PHP, pois o PHP é *backend* e o bootstrap é *frontend*